# Hard disk fails sometimes

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I'm using Ubuntu kernel 3.13.0-48.
Sometimes the system fails to boot. Sometimes it hangs at the boot process just before the welcome login, and sometimes GRUB fails to load the kernel and shows an error message. I have to power off the PC, and try agin to get the system boot.
I have new PC (lenovo Z5070 with 1 TB hard drive (ST1000LM014-SSHD-8GB). I have used it for about 2 months with kernel 3.10.0-37. I did not have this particular issue.

In my kernel log I can see the following error sometimes. It happens with 3.13.0-37 and 3.13.0-48.

```
[   53.745118] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x4000008 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
[   53.745121] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[   53.745124] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   53.745127] ata1.00: cmd 60/20:18:a8:73:46/00:00:02:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 16384 in
[   53.745127]          res 41/84:20:be:73:46/00:00:02:00:00/00 Emask 0x410 (ATA bus error) <F>
[   53.745129] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[   53.745130] ata1.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[   53.745133] ata1: hard resetting link
[   54.062043] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   54.186918] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   54.202155] ata1: EH complete
[  300.127693] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

Comment: I have exactly same laptop with 1TB hard drive I have exactly same problem. I diagnosed the hard drive by tools provided by Lenovo support and Ubuntu both of them dont show any issue in my hard drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was hardware issue. I replaced the hard disk with a new one and the issue is gone.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer. Hit the little checkmark on the left, as I recall. That way others will know it's solved. Good job!